# Issue with Etoken based performance monitorng?

Tags: performance-testing, performance-monitor

We are doing performance monitoring for EToken based applications. One of such application is running in windows 7 machine. It is running properly for few hours only and then the failure monitoring are displayed in HP BSM.

When we checked in system logs using Event Viewer. We found the error message as below:

> A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL client
>   credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic
>   module is 0xc002001b. The internal error state is 10003

Answer (score 1):

If its an failure issue in the BSM and if the actual applications is doing good, then you need to change the run time settings in the VuGen script as below:
in Run time settings --> Under preferences tab check the Use winlet instead of sockets option.